# Detail with spelling in formal letter style file g-brief2

Tags: letters, spelling, german

How can one in the formal letter style file g-brief2, when it is used for German, achieve to have printed the word *Telephon* with this spelling instead of the nowadays more fashionable *Telefon*? I am referring to the section at the bottom of the letter page, where the sender can add the contact details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro that defines the spelling of the telephone section is called `\telefontext`. You can change this into something else after loading the class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,ngerman,latin9]{g-brief2}
\def\telefontext{Telephon\/:}

\TelefonZeileA       {Festnetz: +49 000 0000000}
\TelefonZeileB       {Freecall: +49 800 0000000}
\TelefonZeileC       {Mobil: +49 171 00000000}
\TelefonZeileD       {Fax: +49 0000 000-0000}
\TelefonZeileE       {}
\TelefonZeileF       {}

\Gruss               {Mit freundlichen Gr\"u\ss{}en}{1cm}
\Unterschrift        {Otto Raffzahn}

\begin{document}
\begin{g-brief}

seit der siebten Mieterh\"ohung im laufenden Jahr konnte ich
keinen Zahlungseingang von Ihnen mehr verbuchen. Ich bitte Sie
Ihren Verpflichtungen schnellstens nachzukommen, da ich mich
sonst gezwungen sehe, Ihre Miete ein weiteres mal anzuheben.

\end{g-brief}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great, this works well!